# Django ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'myproject.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I have an almost fresh install of django and when I run `python manage.py runserver`. It is giving me this error:

> ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'myproject.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.

settings.py

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Did you change the directory names after running `startproject` ?

Comment: what's the name of your application ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my experience this happens when I try to execute *runserver* but I haven't installed all custom **MIDDLEWARE** in setting.py. After identifying and installing the middlewares the error is resolved.

Answer (score 18):

Comment out the

> #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',

in your settings.py file in Middleware

Comment: It's better to remove this line, not comment out the code. Also some explanation would be helpful, since this is caused by deleting SessionAuthenticationMiddleware in django 2.0 (which was deprecated earlier in django 1.10).

Answer (score 7):

Check the settings.py,

```
MIDDLEWARE=[
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]
```

remove `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',` or install **[Whitenoise](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#whitenoise)** (*pip install whitenoise*)

Comment: Whitenoise was the problem also for me, I've copied the settings.py from another projects where I did use whitenoise, had to deleted for this one. ty

Answer (score 4):

Check for the stack trace - you might find answer few lines above the line "The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:"

It may caused for example by using of middleware from some uninstalled third party app etc.

Answer (score 4):

One of the reason for this issue is if you have a middleware added into django middleware list in settings.py but haven't installed it yet.

In my case I added `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` which wasn't installed.I installed it using `pip install django-cors-headers` and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem because I added the debug_toolbar Middleware to my settings.py

```
'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
```

I solved the problem by removing the debug_toolbar Middleware. I also had to remove debug_toolbar from my INSTALLED APPS.

Answer (score 1):

For `whitenoise version 4.0` or above:
 - The WSGI integration option for Django (which involved editing wsgi.py) has been removed. Instead, you should add WhiteNoise to your middleware list in settings.py and remove any reference to WhiteNoise from wsgi.py.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

- The `'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'` alias has now been removed. Instead you should use the correct import path: `'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'`.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone having this same issue. i just fixed it following the instructions [here](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0)

you should add WhiteNoise to your middleware list in settings.py and remove any reference to WhiteNoise from wsgi.py.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and in my case, I had made a custom middleware and then added it to the middleware list in `settings.py` under `MIDDLEWARE`. The problem was in the casing that I had used for listing the middleware in the list. I changed it to match the casing of my custom one and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

got the same error when mistakenly registering a app in MIDDLEWARE = [] insted of INSTALLED_APPS = []

Answer (score 0):

In my case, carefully checking the output, I found this

```
in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_session_timeout'
```

This module in most cases is not loaded by default in django packages. You will need to install it `pip install django-session-timeout`