# Adding whitenoise to django gives an "ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application" error

Tags: django, heroku, continuous-integration, gitlab, whitenoise

My application works if I were not to add

```
"whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware"
```

into the MIDDLEWARE in settings.py

but if I were to add it back, then it would not work and would give this error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'story_4.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

This is what is inside my wsgi.py file

```
#wsgi.py

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'story_4.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'myproject.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800726/django-improperlyconfigured-wsgi-application-myproject-wsgi-application-could)

Comment: @bmons There is no such as `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware'`, in my settings.py the nearest I could find was `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'`, and if I were to comment it, it would give another error which is ?: `(admin.E410) 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.`

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, Please remember to update your Whitenoise to the latest version with `pip install --upgrade whitenoise`

Mine was still at 3.3.0 and apparently django didn't like it.